# Format origin and destination data

Tags: r, dataframe, format

I would like to change my data like I show below. Hope, you can help me!

I have this data:

```
Person, Trip,Destination
1, 1,Japan
1,2,US,
2,1,US
2,2, Japan
2,3, China
```

I would like to get this table :

```
Person, Trip,Origin, Destination
1,1,US, Japan
1,2,Japan, US,
2,1,China, US
2,2, US, Japan
2,3, Japan, China
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know about origin in trip 1?

Comment: It assumes that their trip is going back to the first origin on trip 1 for each person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end. The question has sample output but no explanation of how it was calculated so we just assume that it is defined by a rotation of `Destination` within `Person` group.  First define a `rotation` function and then use `ave` to apply it to each `Person` group.  Finally reorder the columns to be in the order shown in the question.  No packages are used.

```
rotate <- function(x) c(tail(x, 1), head(x, -1))
transform(DF, Origin = ave(Destination, Person, FUN = rotate))[c(1:2, 4:3)]
```

giving:

```
  Person Trip Origin Destination
1      1    1     US       Japan
2      1    2  Japan          US
3      2    1  China          US
4      2    2     US       Japan
5      2    3  Japan       China
```

### Note

Removing the trailing comma on the 2nd line of data we assume this input:

```
Lines <- "Person, Trip,Destination
1, 1,Japan
1,2,US
2,1,US
2,2, Japan
2,3, China"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```